# Journal Dashboard Graph widget for odoo 8

Tags: graph, widget, odoo-8, dashboard, odoo-9

I found a widget="dashboard_graph" in Odoo 9 for Account journal dashboard, how can i use this widget in odoo 8. there is a js file in account module for this widget. is it possible to use this js file directly into my own module in odoo 8. pls help[image]